# Next.js redirect if there is no cookie

Tags: reactjs, regex, cookies, next.js

Is there a way to redirect the user from checkout to the join page ONLY if there is no cookie `user_token`. Next.js allows to set only strings and undefined as `value`, but I need to validate that there is no cookie:

```js
  redirects: async () => [
    {
      source: '/checkout',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'cookie',
          key: 'user_token',
          value: '',
        },
      ],
      permanent: true,
      destination: '/join',
    },
  ],
```

I tried to use regex for empty string, but it did not work:

```js
  redirects: async () => [
    {
      source: '/checkout',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'cookie',
          key: 'user_token',
          value: '(^$)',
        },
      ],
      permanent: true,
      destination: '/join',
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Not possible at this point (06/2021), there is no "has not" (already asked the same question). I strongly suggest investing in an additional gateway or proxy server to handle such things

Answer (score 1):

Since nextjs version 12.3.3 (I think), we can use **"missing"** property on nextjs `redirects` configuration:

```
// next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      // if the cookie `user_token` is present,
      // this redirect will NOT be applied
      {
        source: "/checkout",
        missing: [
          {
            type: "cookie",
            key: "user_token",
          },
        ],
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/join",
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem you have is, that you just limit it to an empty cookie.
You will have to check for the absence of a cookie inside the route and send a `res.redirect` from there (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/response-helpers)
And: are you sure you want a permanent redirect?? The browser caches it and those users will be redirected without a request to the server in the future.